# Is there a Cipher function that have fixed result like SHA1 or SHA256 so can be decrypted

Tags: algorithm

Im checking for encrypt or hash content and the codified result should have always the same size.

I tried with `AES` and other algorithms and the result is always variable. Only found that SHA series return a fixed result.

Any ideas ?

I tried different algorithms with no luck

Comment: The key point is to do encrypt('hi', 'key) and that produce a 64 length result. But If I use encrypt('hi this is a test', 'key) should also produce a 64 length result @MrSmith42

Comment: I for example used this and the result always grows https://gist.github.com/angeal185/df1c3fde9dc73f6ae7776584d2f68b3d

Comment: For short inputs you can use padding to get the required output size. For any inputs longer than your required size then you are going to lose information. You might be able to extend the size limit a little by first compressing the plaintext to try to get it below the required size. You will need to uncompress after decryption of course.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot encrypt input of big size to a fixed size block.

(As long as the input size in not limited by an upper bound).

To be able to decrypt the date without loss the encryption must be a bijective mapping from the input domain in the cyper-text domain.
So the cyper-text domain must be at least as big as the input domain.

Therefore if size of the input domain is not limited by an upper bound the cyper-text domain cannot be also.

e.g.
If you want to limit the encrypted output to 64 bit there are only 2^64 possible outputs. So you can at most encrypt 2^64 different inputs without getting any collisions. If you cannot limit the possible inputs to this upper bound it is impossible to use 64bit and expect to be able to decrypt it again correctly
.